# How to deal with this situation building a REST API?

Tags: rest, backbone.js, marionette

I got this problem, I have built a rest api and I don't know how to deal with this:
When the javascript client (Marionette.js) is in charge of making the views, I don't have problems, because as it is known, it just requests an url (e.g. example.com/user/37), the server  retrieves a json with {id:'37', name:'Peter', age:'24'} (there is one controller class named User) and Marionette shows that data in the view. But if the user enter to example.com/user/37 by the browser it will show just {id:'37', name:'Peter', age:'24'} without any view. What can I do if I want to see the same view in both cases?

Comment: It shouldn't be the rest api's responsibility to enforce any particular type of client. Your marionette based application is just one client.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to serve up HTML or JSON from the same endpoint then your server should be making that decision based on the request's `Accept` header. If the request's `Accept` header is `application/json` then your server should return just the JSON ortherwise return the HTML.

You can see that [SoundCloud uses the same technique](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference) for returning XML or JSON from their API:

> Resources are returned as XML by default, or JSON if a .json extension is appended to the resource URI. We encourage you to use JSON. You can also send an appropriate `Accept` header specifying the format you would like. For example, a request with the header `Accept: application/json` will return resources represented as a JSON document.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is pratically impossible.

why ?

When your first enter the url `example.com` it's the server that responds with all the artifacts that compose your application (html, js, css ...) and the browser display it.

Now, when you enter ther url `example.com/user/37` the server only sends the JSON data without any html, js or css, so the browser display the raw data he received.

What you are trying to do is to force the server to give two responses (JSON or html/js/css) depending on the user request.

You can do it, but it would be so complicated that's not worth the efforts.